# Add one day to a date field in all cells in a row - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date, addition

I have a date (2/1/2018)in D1 cell and now I want to increase date by one in all cells from D2 to AH using VBA

Any suggestion ?

THanks
Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that if variable data type is set as `Date` it will increasing day of date when summing with 1.

### VBA:

```
Sub DateIncreaser

    Dim d as Date
    d = Selection.value 'Assign appropriated value to d variable.
    d = d + 1
    debug.print d 'This optional line shows the result in immediate window.
    Range("D2").Value = d

End Sub
```

### Update1

```
Sub DateIncreaser()

    Dim d As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim InitialColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim FinalColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim RowsIndex As Long

    InitialColumnIndex = 1
    FinalColumnIndex = 34 'Representative AH Column
    RowsIndex = 2
    d = Selection.Value 'Source date value

    For i = InitialColumnIndex To FinalColumnIndex
        d = d + 1
        Cells(RowsIndex, i).Value = d
    Next i

End Sub
```

### Update2

```
Sub DateIncreaser()

    Dim d As Date
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim InitialColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim FinalColumnIndex As Integer
    Dim RowsIndex As Long

    InitialColumnIndex = 1
    FinalColumnIndex = 34 'Representative AH Column
    RowsIndex = 2

    For j = 1 To Sheets.Count

        d = Range("D1").Value 'Source date value

        For i = InitialColumnIndex To FinalColumnIndex
            d = d + 1
            Worksheets(j).Cells(RowsIndex, i).Value = d
        Next i

    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. as per your code it will put incremented value in D2  alone. I need to repeat this for all cells from D2 to AH. I have used Range("E1").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(Range("D1"))). But here also it will just put the incremented value in E1 . And I need to repeat same line of code for all cells. Any alternative for that?

Comment: The Update was sent.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. If I want to put the date in Cell D1 of all sheets(Here sheet names are Jan,Feb,Mar etc) I tried below code. But it didn't work.                                                                                             
 For j = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheetname = Sheets(j).Name
Worksheets("&Sheetname".Cells(RowsIndex, j).Value)=CDate(mm & "/01/" & Yr).                          Can you help here?(in this case mm has 01,02,03 etc which corresponds to jan,feb etc and Yr will have YYYY year)

Comment: Please check update2. If true, Please accept my answer with click on tick mark under answer vote at left side of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am new to this forum . I did accept your solution.